# Cell image disppears when the tableview scrolled manually

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

My class has a tableview .Based on the selected index I am reloading my TableView row

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

   [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    [self.stopsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath  

   indexPathForRow:rowNum inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


}
```

rowNum will be set as:rowNum = indexPath.row

Based on this I make the hidden image for the particular cell visible. This works fine . But

when I scroll my tableview manually(i.e when I cell goes out of the view or visibility) my hidden image for the cell disappears because value

for the  rowNum will be lost . Any help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because when the cell goes out of visibility , `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called again , and that time a new cell is created or existing cell is used depending on the `cellIndentifier`

Hence , if you are using less number of cells You can assign different `cellIdentifier`s for different cells , and then even if the cell goes out of visibility , It would still remain the same cell

You can do this as follows : in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
 NSString *str = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"cell%d",indexpath.row];

 cell = [UITableView dequeReusableCellWithCellIdentifier:str];

 if(cell == nil)
 {
  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:str];
 }

 return cell ;
```

This would definitely work !!!

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure why you have such code in viewWillAppear, here's what I understand

- You alter display of clicked cell
- Your problem is, when you scroll, the state of the cell is lost

For this I can suggest the following:

In your view controller, declare a property (e.g. `NSMutableArray`) that stores each cell's state. And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, initialise your cell with the right state

To give you some background information, cells are reused in iOS by default to improve performance. So the UITableViewCell objects that you return from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are constantly reused in other rows. Hence, setting state on a cell will not persist when you scroll (that same object will be used for another row). That's why you should maintain that state information via an external property as I suggested